# UITableView with custom cells lags while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uitableview, autolayout

My problem is that `UITableView` lags quite a lot while scrolling.

[This is what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL12P.jpg)

Starting from the top I have a simple section header with only one checkbox and one `UILabel`. Under this header, you can see a custom cell with only one `UILabel` aligned to the center. This custom cell works like another header for the data that would be shown below (Basically a 3D array). Under these "headers" are custom cells that contain one multiline `UILabel` and under this label is a container for a variable amount of lines containing a checkbox and an `UILabel`. On the right side of the cell is also a button (blue/white arrow).

So this means the content is shown like this:

- Section header (containing day and date)
- Custom UITableViewCell = header (containing some header information)
- Custom UITableViewCell (containing data to be shown)

Here is my code:

**cellForRowAt:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let (isHeader, headerNumber, semiResult) = checkIfIsHeader(section: indexPath.section, row: indexPath.row)

        let row = indexPath.row

        if isHeader {
            let chod = objednavkaDny[indexPath.section].chody[headerNumber+1]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellHeaderReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ObjednavkyHeaderTableViewCell
            cell.titleLabel.text = chod.popisPoradiJidla
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }else{
            let chod = objednavkaDny[indexPath.section].chody[headerNumber]

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ObjednavkyTableViewCell
            cell.updateData(objednavka: chod.objednavky[row-semiResult], canSetAmount: self.typDialogu == 3)
            return cell
        }
    }
```

**checkIfIsHeader:**

```
func checkIfIsHeader(section: Int, row: Int) -> (Bool, Int, Int){
        if let cachedResult = checkIfHeaderCache[section]?[row] {
            return (cachedResult[0] == 1, cachedResult[1], cachedResult[2])
        }

        var isHeader = false

        var semiResult = 0
        var headerNumber = -1

        for (index, chod) in objednavkaDny[section].chody.enumerated() {
            let sum = chod.objednavky.count
            if row == semiResult {
                isHeader = true
                break
            }else if row < semiResult {
                semiResult -= objednavkaDny[section].chody[index-1].objednavky.count
                break
            }else {
                headerNumber += 1
                semiResult += 1
                if index != objednavkaDny[section].chody.count - 1 {
                    semiResult += sum
                }
            }
        }
        checkIfHeaderCache[section] = [Int:[Int]]()
        checkIfHeaderCache[section]![row] = [isHeader ? 1 : 0, headerNumber, semiResult]
        return (isHeader, headerNumber, semiResult)
    }
```

**and the main cell that shows the data:**

```
class ObjednavkyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    lazy var numberTextField: ObjednavkyTextField = {
        let textField = ObjednavkyTextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textField
    }()

    let mealLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.font = UIFont(name: ".SFUIText", size: 15)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.backgroundColor = .white
        label.isOpaque = true
        return label
    }()


    lazy var detailsButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow-right")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        button.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.custom.blue.classicBlue
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(detailsButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.isOpaque = true
        return button
    }()

    let pricesContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.isOpaque = true
        return view
    }()


    var canSetAmount = false {
        didSet {
            canSetAmount ? showNumberTextField() : hideNumberTextField()
        }
    }


    var shouldShowPrices = false {
        didSet {
            shouldShowPrices ? showPricesContainerView() : hidePricesContainerView()
        }
    }

    var pricesContainerHeight: CGFloat = 0

    private let priceViewHeight: CGFloat = 30

    var mealLabelLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var mealLabelBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var pricesContainerViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var pricesContainerViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.selectionStyle = .none
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    @objc func detailsButtonPressed() {

    }


    func updateData(objednavka: Objednavka, canSetAmount: Bool) {
        self.canSetAmount = canSetAmount
        if let popisJidla = objednavka.popisJidla, popisJidla != "", popisJidla != " " {
            self.mealLabel.text = popisJidla
        }else{
            self.mealLabel.text = objednavka.nazevJidelnicku
        }


        if objednavka.objects.count > 1 {
            shouldShowPrices = true
            setPricesStackView(with: objednavka.objects)
            checkIfSelected(objects: objednavka.objects)
        }else{
            shouldShowPrices = false
            self.numberTextField.text = String(objednavka.objects[0].pocet)
            //setSelected(objednavka.objects[0].pocet > 0, animated: false)
            objednavka.objects[0].pocet > 0 ? setSelectedStyle() : setDeselectedStyle()
        }
    }

    //---------------

    func checkIfSelected(objects: [ObjednavkaObject]) {
        var didChangeSelection = false
        for object in objects {          // Checks wether cell should be selected or not
            if object.pocet > 0 {
                setSelected(true, animated: false)
                setSelectedStyle()
                didChangeSelection = true
                break
            }
        }
        if !didChangeSelection {
            setSelected(false, animated: false)
            setDeselectedStyle()
        }
    }


    //--------------

    func showNumberTextField() {
        numberTextField.isHidden = false

        mealLabelLeadingConstraint?.isActive = false
        mealLabelLeadingConstraint = mealLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberTextField.trailingAnchor, constant: 10)
        mealLabelLeadingConstraint?.isActive = true
    }

    func hideNumberTextField() {
        numberTextField.isHidden = true

        mealLabelLeadingConstraint?.isActive = false
        mealLabelLeadingConstraint = mealLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
        mealLabelLeadingConstraint?.isActive = true
    }

    func showPricesContainerView() {
        hideNumberTextField()

        pricesContainerView.isHidden = false

        mealLabelBottomConstraint?.isActive = false
        pricesContainerViewBottomConstraint?.isActive = true
    }

    func hidePricesContainerView() {
        pricesContainerView.isHidden = true

        pricesContainerViewBottomConstraint?.isActive = false
        mealLabelBottomConstraint?.isActive = true
    }

    //--------------

    func setSelectedStyle() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.custom.blue.classicBlue
        mealLabel.textColor = .white
        mealLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.custom.blue.classicBlue

        for subview in pricesContainerView.subviews where subview is ObjednavkyPriceView {
            let priceView = (subview as! ObjednavkyPriceView)
            priceView.titleLabel.textColor = .white
            priceView.checkBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.custom.blue.classicBlue
            priceView.titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.custom.blue.classicBlue
            priceView.backgroundColor = UIColor.custom.blue.classicBlue
        }

        pricesContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.custom.blue.classicBlue

        detailsButton.imageView?.tintColor = .white
        detailsButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.custom.blue.classicBlue

    }

    func setDeselectedStyle() {
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        mealLabel.textColor = .black
        mealLabel.backgroundColor = .white

        for subview in pricesContainerView.subviews where subview is ObjednavkyPriceView {
            let priceView = (subview as! ObjednavkyPriceView)
            priceView.titleLabel.textColor = .black
            priceView.checkBox.backgroundColor = .white
            priceView.titleLabel.backgroundColor = .white
            priceView.backgroundColor = .white
        }

        pricesContainerView.backgroundColor = .white

        detailsButton.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.custom.blue.classicBlue
        detailsButton.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    //-----------------

    func setPricesStackView(with objects: [ObjednavkaObject]) {
        let subviews = pricesContainerView.subviews
        var subviewsToDelete = subviews.count

        for (index, object) in objects.enumerated() {
            subviewsToDelete -= 1
            if subviews.count - 1 >= index {
                let priceView = subviews[index] as! ObjednavkyPriceView
                priceView.titleLabel.text = object.popisProduktu  // + " " + NSNumber(value: object.cena).getFormattedString(currencySymbol: "Kč") // TODO: currencySymbol
                priceView.canSetAmount = canSetAmount
                priceView.count = object.pocet
                priceView.canOrder = (object.nelzeObj == nil || object.nelzeObj == "")
            }else {
                let priceView = ObjednavkyPriceView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(index) * priceViewHeight + CGFloat(index * 5), width: pricesContainerView.frame.width, height: priceViewHeight))
                pricesContainerView.addSubview(priceView)
                priceView.titleLabel.text = object.popisProduktu  // + " " + NSNumber(value: object.cena).getFormattedString(currencySymbol: "Kč") // TODO: currencySymbol
                priceView.numberTextField.delegate = self
                priceView.canSetAmount = canSetAmount
                priceView.canOrder = (object.nelzeObj == nil || object.nelzeObj == "")
                priceView.count = object.pocet
                pricesContainerHeight += ((index == 0) ? 30 : 35)
            }
        }

        if subviewsToDelete > 0 {  // Deletes unwanted subviews
            for _ in 0..<subviewsToDelete {
                pricesContainerView.subviews.last?.removeFromSuperview()
                pricesContainerHeight -= pricesContainerHeight + 5
            }
        }

        if pricesContainerHeight < 0 {
            pricesContainerHeight = 0
        }

        pricesContainerViewHeightConstraint?.constant = pricesContainerHeight
    }

    func setupView() {
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        self.backgroundColor = .white

        contentView.addSubview(numberTextField)
        contentView.addSubview(mealLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(detailsButton)
        contentView.addSubview(pricesContainerView)

        setupConstraints()
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        numberTextField.anchor(leading: readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        numberTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mealLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        detailsButton.anchor(trailing: readableContentGuide.trailingAnchor, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        detailsButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        mealLabel.anchor(top: contentView.topAnchor, trailing: detailsButton.leadingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -10))
        mealLabelBottomConstraint = mealLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10)
        mealLabelBottomConstraint?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)

        pricesContainerView.anchor(top: mealLabel.bottomAnchor, leading: readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor, trailing: detailsButton.leadingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -10))
        pricesContainerViewBottomConstraint = pricesContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10)
        pricesContainerViewBottomConstraint?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)

        pricesContainerViewHeightConstraint = pricesContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        pricesContainerViewHeightConstraint?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
        pricesContainerViewHeightConstraint?.isActive = true
    }
}
```

To conclude how it is done:

- `tableView.rowHeight` is set to `UITableViewAutomaticDymension`
- inside `cellForRowAt` I get the data from an array and give it to the
  cell
- all the cells are set up in code using constraints
- all the views have set `isOpaque = true`
- heights of the cells are cached
- cells are set to rasterize

I also noticed that it lags at certain scroll levels and that sometimes it works just fine and sometimes it lags a lot.

Despite all of the optimization I have done, the tableView still lags while scrolling.

[Here is a screenshot from Instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKcfc.png)

Any tip how to improve the scrolling performance is highly appreciated!

(I might have forgotten to include some code/information so feel free to ask me in the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you where the lag happens exactly but when we are talking about lagging during scrolling, it's related to your `cellForRowAt` delegate method. What happends is that too many things are going on within this method and it's called for every cells that are displaying & going to display. I see that your are trying to cache the result by `checkIfHeaderCache` but still, there is a for loop at the very beginning to determine header cell.

**Suggestions:**
I don't know where you get data (`objednavkaDny`) from but right after you get the data, do a full loop through and determin cell type one by one, and save the result some where base on your design. During this loading time, you can show some loading message on the screen. Then, within the `cellForRow` method, you should be just simply using things like

```
if (isHeader) {
  render header cell
} else {
  render other cell
}
```

**Bottom line:**
`cellForRow` method is not designed to handle heavy calculations, and it will slow down the scrolling if you do so. This method is for assigning values to the cached table view cell only and that's the only thing it is good at.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get the data from an API so it loads the data from the internet and then reloads the tableView. The problem might be worse because as you said I am caching the results. However after scrolling thru all the cells and scrolling back to top, the scrolling is still laggy even though the results are cached, so I am not sure if pre-calculating will help.

Comment: Isn't the problem associated with changing the constraints of the cell inside cellForRowAt ?

Comment: @Phyber No. Changing constraints, resizing elements, etc. are totaly valid and correct way to update cells within `cellForRow`. At this point, you have to try to comment out some code in your `cellForRowAt` to see if it works or not. Your cache functions looks fine for me as long as it gets triggered.

Comment: @Phyber Start with commenting out `cell.updateData` in your `cellForRow` method, as I see tons of calculations and for loops there. Note that big for loops are bad practice in `cellForRow` as you are creating O(n^2) complexity. Please consider preloading your data into a ordered list or a hashmap so that you can get value base on indexPath or key

Comment: OK, so I commented out the for loop inside the cell and updateData now contains only 8 lines or so. I would say that it helped however it still lags a bit even though all things being performed inside cellForRow are only assigning values and changing constraints.

Comment: It seems that fast scrolling doesn't lag as much as slow scrolling. Also there seems to be spots where it lags everytime I scroll by.

Comment: @Phyber Well the fastest way to figure out the root cause is to keep commenting out stuff until your table view is back to normal. Then start to bring code back until you hit the point that it starts to slow. I cannot get my hand on your code so you have to do it by yourself. My next suggestion is to completely comment out this line in your `cellForRow` so that you are just returning an empty cell, and see if that helps. `cell.updateData(objednavka: chod.objednavky[row-semiResult], canSetAmount: self.typDialogu == 3)`